# How to map ID values (int) to String values in C#

Tags: c#

I have a list of IDs that represent different things. I want to display these IDs as strings.

For example the number `12` would map to `"foo"`, and 13 would map to `"bar"`

more specifically i'm attempting to migrate the model properties to a list with the transformed string values. Here is what I have currently

```
var model = new PaymentExclusionModel
{
    ExclusionList = response.Exclusions,
};
List<PaymentProcessorExclusionModel> list = new List<PaymentProcessorExclusionModel>();
list = response.Exclusions.Select(x => new PaymentProcessorExclusionModel
{
    // Convert
});
```

I know what values to map the integers to strings, since it's a small set of values. I have attempted to use a `Dictionary<int, string>` but I get an error complaining about converting an int? to int (int? is from metadata dll and I can't change that).

Here is the code:

```
var model = new PaymentExclusionModel
            {
                ExclusionList = response.Exclusions,
            };
            List<PaymentProcessorExclusionModel> list = new List<PaymentProcessorExclusionModel>();
            list = response.Exclusions.Select(x => new PaymentProcessorExclusionModel
            {
                PaymentType = dict[x.PaymentTypeId.Value]
            });
```

Error Code:

```
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DK.Fin.Secure.Mjolnir.Web.Models.PaymentProcessorExclusionModel>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Web.Models.PaymentProcessorExclusionModel>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: Can you use a `Dictionary<int, string>` ?

Comment: How do you know `12` maps to `"foo"`, i.e., where/what datastructure holds the existing mapping?

Comment: When I use a Dictionary, i.e, `Type=  dict[x.Type]`, I get the `Cannot convert from int? to int`, and the x.Type property is a dll so I can't change that value.

Comment: @kebabTiger `Type= dict[x.Type.GetValueOrDefault(-1)]` -- and make sure you have a dummy entry for `-1`. Or else use `dict.TryGetValue()`

Comment: or you can use `Dictionary<int?, string>`

Comment: It says an `explicit conversion exists`

Comment: Please include the specifics of how you map from `12` to `"foo"`.  You mention a `int?` in the comments, but it's unclear how this relates to your question.  Please [edit] your question with these details.

Comment: @ryanyuyu i am trying to map int values to specific strings, i've tried using a dictionary and i am having issues with explicit casts

Comment: Nullables have a property called [`.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6(v=vs.110).aspx) that you should be able to use.  If needed, null check ahead of time, but `.Value` is of the underlying type.

Comment: This sounds like a great place for an enum to me...  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Comment: I tried that as well, but `An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast)` keeps showing

Comment: Is the line with the .select where it's giving you the exception or is it somewhere else?

Comment: Yeah, that entire block gives that error

Comment: @kebabTiger Mapping an `int` to a `string` is easy, people showed you can use `Dictionary<int, string>`, or an `enum`, or custom classes, etc. IMO your question is unclear because you are not having issues with mapping an `int` to a `string`, you are having issues working with a nullable int `int?`. Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx).

Comment: As I said, the `Dictionary` and `enum` methods both result in the same issue, and I have tried using `.Value` and the other `Nullable` methods

Comment: We can fix your issue working with nullable int's if you show us the code that is giving you the errors; you have not shown us any code with `int` or `int?` anywhere at all, so there's no way for us to help you with your conversion problems. Currently we only have completely unrelated code because your question is not about nullable ints. Pretty sure SO wants you to ask a new question, not to change the premise of your original question in the comments and try to get the new one answered without showing any code or updating the original question at all.

Comment: Try adding `.ToList()` at the end of your `Select`: `list = response.Exclusions.Select(stuff).ToList();`

Comment: @Quantic It takes away the errors, but when I run, `System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value` error

Comment: Yes, as mentioned many times in this thread you can get that error when a nullable type is null (probably other ways to get it to).You need to do something like this: `if (x.PaymentTypeId.HasValue) { use x.PaymentTypeId.Value } else { DON'T USE x.PaymentTypeId.Value BECAUSE IT HAS NO VALUE }`

Comment: `list = response.Exclusions.Select(x => new PaymentProcessorExclusionModel
            {
                PaymentType = PaymentTypeModel.GetMyType(x.PaymentTypeId == null ? 0 : (int)x.PaymentTypeId).Name
            }).ToList();`

gives same error which handles the null values

Answer (score 1):

Here is an enum-style solution:

```
public class MyType : EnumClass
{
    public static MyType FOO = new MyType(12, "Foo");
    public static MyType BAR = new MyType(13, "Bar");
    public static MyType X = new MyType(99, "X");

    [JsonConstructor]
    private MyType(int id, string name)
    {
        _id = id;
        _name = name;
    }

    public static MyType GetMyType(int id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
            case 12: return FOO;
            case 13: return BAR;
            case 99: return X;
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<MyType> GetMyTypes()
    {
        return new List<MyType>
        {
            FOO,
            BAR,
            X
        };
    }
}
```

I've used this type of thing with GREAT success.  I had a poker app and in that case the 'MyType' was 'Card' with all of the attributes of a playing card (suit, number, etc).

The EnumClass

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyProj.MyPath
{
    public abstract class EnumClass
    {
        protected int _id;
        protected string _name;

        public virtual int ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
        }

        public virtual string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return ID.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is EnumClass)
                return ID == (obj as EnumClass).ID;

            return base.Equals(obj);
        }

        public static bool operator ==(EnumClass left, EnumClass right)
        {
            if ((left as Object) == null)
                return (right as Object) == null;

            return left.Equals(right);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(EnumClass left, EnumClass right)
        {
            if ((left as Object) == null)
                return (right as Object) != null;

            return !left.Equals(right);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did _id and _name come from?

Comment: The _id and _name are private attributes inherited from EnumClass which I of course forgot to include....  I'll edit the response with that info.

Comment: So then inside the Select block, i'd do
`PaymentType = PaymentTypeModel.GetMyType(x.PaymentProcessorExclusionId);`, but i get this error: `Cannot convert PaymentTypeModel to string`

Comment: Try PaymentType = PaymentTypeModel.GetMyType(x.PaymentProcessorExclusionId).Name

Comment: The real power in this 'Enum-ish' solution is that you could have several attributes on the enum.  As I mentioned with my Card class, I could have the Suit, Number, Name, ShortName (like 9c for '9 of clubs'), etc.  After .GetCardType(20).Name or .GetCardType(20).Number, etc to get the specific attributes.

Comment: It's a good solution, but it still has the casting issue between int and int?,explicitly on the `x.PaymentTypeId` part

Comment: Well, as you mentioned, you can't change the Int?.  You'll end up having to use .Value or maybe adding checks around it (probably both).

Answer (score -1):

I don't really get why but i believe you want to create an array map between string and int values.
First you would want to use a dictionary

```
Dictionary<int, string> map = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

Then simply add your values

```
map.Add(12, 'foo');
map.Add(13, 'bar');
```

Then basically all you have to do is call the dictionary like an array

```
list = response.Exclusions.Select(x => new PaymentProcessorExclusionModel
{
   NewId = map.ContainsKey(x) ? map[x] : "defaultkey?"
});
```

This is obviously the way to go. Try creating your 'list' variable dynamically like so

```
var list = response.Exclusions.Select(x => new PaymentProcessorExclusionModel
        {
            PaymentType = dict[x.PaymentTypeId.Value]
        });
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but I get explicit casting issues, as mentioned above

Comment: You're getting a type cast error because you're trying to assign an IEnumerable Object returned by the Select function to a variable of type List. See my edited answer. Hope this helps :)